# Why am I unable to replace these NA values in one column of my dataframe based on the values in another? [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a data frame (`df3`) with 2 columns: `SUBSCRIBE` and `Weeks3Meals`.

`Subscribe` is a categorical variable and can take values (`Y`, `N`) and `Weeks3Meals` is of type `float`. Both contain missing values (`NaN`).

Original Dataframe :

[image: Original Dataframe]

I want to replace with `Y`, all cells having `NA` in `Subscribe` if the corresponding `Weeks3Meals` cell is not `NA`.

So for example, I want to replace `NA` value of `SUBSCRIBE` in row `3` with `Y` since `Weeks3Meals` cell is not `NA` but has a value  ; see following image :

[image: rows with NA in Subcribe but where 'Weeks3Meals' is not NA]

This is what I tried to do :

```
df3['SUBSCRIBE'][df3['Weeks3Meals'].notnull()].fillna('Y', inplace = True).
```

But when I print out the data frame, the `NA` value is not replaced and the rows remain the same :

[image: DF after running code]

I'm not sure why it's not working. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did use `fillna` in my original code above but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

`df3.loc[(df3['Weeks3Meals'].notnull()) & (df3['SUBSCRIBE'].isnull()), 'SUBSCRIBE'] ='Y'`

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you by any chance know why the code with `fillna` doesn't work?

Comment: I see what you were trying to do with `fillna` but you have two conditions here so you cannot chain them together and `fillna` the resulting dataframe. If you do that the `fillna` will return the subset of the dataframe that you filtered using the two conditions and fill the `nan` of that subset but then it will be difficult to join it back to the original dataframe

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification!